# Java TableViewer - change cell image on selection

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

I have followed Vogella's tutorial on Table Viewer and using the StyledCellLabelProvider presented there. It creates a CHECKED or UNCHECKED icon on the third column

```
    col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[3], bounds[3], 3);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Image getImage(Object element) {
            if (((Person) element).isMarried()) {
                return CHECKED;
            } else {
                return UNCHECKED;
            }
        }
    });
    col.setEditingSupport(new MarriedEditingSupport(viewer));
```

The column images get painted accordingly when the table is created but how can I change the icon when the user clicks a cell ? (I want to simulate a check box)

Comment: Thia is jFace code - what has it got to do with Swing?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Andrew this code looks like JFace to me, I think the Swing tag is the incorrect one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `EditingSupport` class based on `CheckboxCellEditor` for this:

```
class MarriedEditingSupport extends EditingSupport
{
  private final CheckboxCellEditor _editor;

  MarriedEditingSupport(TableViewer viewer)
  {
    super(viewer);

    _editor = new CheckboxCellEditor(viewer.getTable());
  }

  @Override
  protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element)
  {
    return _editor;
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean canEdit(Object element)
  {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  protected Object getValue(Object element)
  {
    return Boolean.valueOf(((Person)element).isMarried());
  }

  @Override
  protected void setValue(Object element, Object value)
  {
    ((Person)element).setMarried(((Boolean)value).booleanValue());

    getViewer().update(element, null);
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked but using the viewer update method only makes the visual changes after I move my cursor to the cell. Instead I used viewer's table redraw method (It doesn't contain many rows). Although this one updates the icons correctly, if I click ON/OFF really fast it gets locked. Guess it's not that fast after all.. Do you have any other idea on how I could refresh the viewer after a check is made ? viewer.refresh() does not work.

Comment: This code is based on something I use, but my label provider is based on `OwnerDrawLabelProvider`.. I can't reproduce any problems with that.